# How to do a synchronous XMLHttpRequest in Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app

Using the following code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
```

Yields the following error:

Uncaught InvalidAccessError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Synchronous requests are disabled for this page.

Is it simply not possible, or am I doing it wrong? Do I need extra permissions?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that ?

Comment: @adeneo could be useful within a web-worker, where there is no concern of blocking the UI thread

Comment: PDFJS uses it in the viewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synchronous `XMLHttpRequests` are disabled by default for Chrome apps.

Check [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) to see all disabled web features and the workarounds. For this case:

> Use async-only XMLHttpRequest: [Getting Rid of Synchrounous XXRs.](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs)