# Can Service Workers respond to synchronous XHR requests?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, service-worker, fetch-api

I would like to use Service Workers to enhance an existing web site. In particular, I would like to add better offline support by having Service Workers respond to requests with placeholder resources when the actual resources are not available. This approach had been working, but I've encountered an obstacle. There are a few places in the site where *synchronous* XHR requests are used to load certain resources, and my Service Worker doesn't receive events for them in Chrome. (Please don't suggest eliminating synchronous XHR requests. That's desired, but out-of-scope.)

Is it supposed to be possible for a Service Worker to respond to synchronous XHR requests? I could imagine this being complicated to implement, and would understand if it wasn't supported. A "correct" answer should exist between the [W3C Service Workers Specification (Working Draft)](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/) and the [WHATWG Fetch Specification (Living Standard)](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/), but I haven't finished deciphering them. I would appreciate an explanation of how the specifications describe whether or not this should be supported, and/or any references to discussions about specifying or implementing this behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### In Theory

Yes, service workers should be able to respond to synchronous XHR requests. This isn't explicitly stated in the specifications, but there's no exception that would cause synchronous XHR requests to be treated differently, and the W3C Web Platform Tests (WPT) suite has a test case to verify that it's supported: [`wpt/service-workers/service-worker/fetch-request-xhr-sync.https.html`](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/service-workers/service-worker/fetch-request-xhr-sync.https.html).

#### In Practice

As of January 2019, service workers can respond to synchronous XHR requests in Firefox and Edge, but not in Chrome or Safari. Chrome is [planning to add support soon](https://crbug.com/602051), but we don't know if Safari ever will.

An up-to-date browser support matrix is available [at WPT.fyi](https://wpt.fyi/results/service-workers/service-worker/fetch-request-xhr-sync.https.html). You can run the WPT test case in your own browser at https://w3c-test.org/service-workers/service-worker/fetch-request-xhr-sync.https.html.

Comment: I think the "planning in adding support soon" part could be removed, since it has been two years, and judging by the comments, they don't have this set as a priority.

Comment: **Important Note:** Service workers appear to be able to respond to synchronous XHR requests *sent from a web worker* - at least in my experiments so far. I don't have anything official on this so I don't know if it's guaranteed but I've tested Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Sending the requests from a web worker is my use case and this post had me worried, but when I looked at the WPT test case I guessed that the reason it didn't work was probably (hopefully) because the request was sent from the main thread.

Comment: I can verify that if the synchronous requests are made from the main thread, they are not intercepted from the service worker!

Answer (score 6):

According to [XMLHttpRequest spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org), the [fetch procedure for both synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-send) is the [same](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-fetch) so, in theory, it should be intercepted but [Synchronous XHR has been deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) so I would not expect Chrome to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a synchronous effect by chaining asynchronous calls together. It creates indented callbacks - whereas promises would make the code easier to read - but the 2nd Ajax call won't be made until after the 1st one has returned. Note that the 3rd parameter is set to true in both calls.

```
// Synchronized Ajax calls using 2 nested Asynchronous calls

// Asynchronous request #1 using traditional API
const axhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
axhr.open('GET', '/__so-example__', true);
axhr.onload = event => {
  console.log("A-XHR: " + axhr.responseText);

  // Asynchronous request #2 using traditional API
  const sxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  sxhr.open('GET', '/__so-example__', true);
  sxhr.onload = event => {
    console.log("S-XHR: " + sxhr.responseText);
  }
  sxhr.send();
}
axhr.send();
```

It's just an example. I assume that promises could be chained just as easily (but vertically stacked, instead of right indented) to create a synchronous effect.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to do in Chrome. See these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693814/how-to-do-a-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-app  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs?hl=en

Comment: According to Comments #23-27 of this Chromium Bugs list post, sync XHR should still work for Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=392311 I don't know why it's not working for your code example above: "S-XHR: [not found]", but I was trying to help you fix that. The links simply show that people have asked before on SO "Will Chrome and other browsers drop support for Synchronous XMLHttpRequest?" The answers on SO suggest "yes", but Chrome devs said "no": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876093/will-chrome-and-other-browsers-drop-support-for-synchronous-xmlhttprequest