# How to make Axios use Fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest, axios, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

I am beginner in the PWA and I try to get my code to call an API and then store it in the browser's cache. But I see that axios uses the XMLHttpRequest and not the fetch API, so I can't cache my API call.

I use workbox for the service worker and vue cli.
my service-worker.js :

```
   workbox.setConfig({
    debug: false,
  });

  workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

  //image in cache
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
      cacheName: 'images',
      plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
          maxEntries: 60,
          maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );

  //network request in cache
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/'),
    workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
      cacheName: 'api',
    }),
  );

  //js and css in cache
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:js|css)$/,
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate(),
  ); 

  //webfont in cache
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('https://fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com/(.*)'),
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'googleapis',
      plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
          maxEntries: 30,
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );
```

my registerServiceWorker.js :

```
   import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      )
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
         console.log('content in cached');
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {

    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

and my call API :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import CONSTANTS from '../constants/constants';
import exception_manager from 'exception_manager';

export default {
    getGiphy() {
        return Vue.axios.get(`${CONSTANTS.SERVER_ADDRESS}search?q=cat&api_key=${CONSTANTS.API_KEY}&limit=9`).catch(error => {
            exception_manager.handleException(error, 'GiphyService.js', 8, window, CONSTANTS.ERROR_SERVER_ADDRESS);
        });

    }
}
```

I think that's really the story with the xmlhttprequest, but I'm not sure.
On the other hand, js, css and images files are well cached

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Although I agree that protocol needs to be `https` to use Service Worker, `XMLHttpRequest` could be the reason as well. Actually I had the same issue and in my case, needed to replace `XMLHttpRequest` with `fetch` to make it work for offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RegExp route inside of the service worker looks for `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/`, which is an `http:` URL. Service workers will only intercept secure requests, which means `https:` (or `http://localhost`).

Make sure that you're using `https:` in your client-side Vue code, and adjust your Workbox configuration to use `https:` as well.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question? Or rather, does workbox do proper caching with current axios/XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Asynchronous XMLHttpRequests will trigger a service worker's `fetch` handler. Synchronous XMLHttpRequests might not in certain browsers (but they're not a good idea in modern code): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54319282/385997