# Can I cache api call which is handled by XMLHttpRequest not fetch?

Tags: fetch, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm trying to cache API call which is handled by `XMLHttpRequest` with using Workbox. I successfully cached API calls in Cache Storage. However, the request to cached data fails when I switched to offline although the data is in Cache Storage. Then I replaced the method using `XMLHttpRequest` with fetch event and it pulled the cached data and renders the element in offline.

So, I would like to know whether there is a workaround to use `XMLHttpRequest` not fetch.

The reason I'm asking is that I am planning to cache API call for multiple  many pages but most of the widgets in my workplace is using `jQuery` Ajax. I'm afraid that we need to replace the method Ajax with fetch one-by-one.

Comment: You should be able to intercept XMLHttpRequest, unless it is a synchronous request - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879844/can-service-workers-respond-to-synchronous-xhr-requests

Comment: Thank you for the URL. That answers my question!