# Can service worker intercept ajax requests?

Tags: service-worker

According to MDN:

> The onfetch property of the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope interface is an event handler fired whenever a fetch event occurs (usually when the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.fetch() method is called.)

Does this mean that service worker can only intercept requests sent by `fetch()` from main thread? How about ajax requests? Is there any way to intercept them through service worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fetch events](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-global-scope-fetch-event) are sent when any resource is being [fetched through HTTP](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-fetch), be it scripts, medias, links etc., and XHR.

So yes, a ServiceWorker should intercept XHR requests (though [synchronous ones are only intercepted in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879844/can-service-workers-respond-to-synchronous-xhr-requests)...)